# volume backup create what is errno 22?

Tags: openstack, openstack-cinder

Trying to create a volume backup both using the web UI and the cmd and keep getting errno 22. I'm unable to find information about the error or how to fix it. Anyone knows where I should start looking?

```
(openstack) volume backup create --force --name inventory01_vol_backups 398ee974-9b83-4918-9935-f52882b3e6b7
(openstack) volume backup show inventory01_vol_backups
+-----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Field                 | Value                                                            |
+-----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| availability_zone     | None                                                             |
| container             | None                                                             |
| created_at            | 2021-08-03T23:45:49.000000                                       |
| data_timestamp        | 2021-08-03T23:45:49.000000                                       |
| description           | None                                                             |
| fail_reason           | [errno 22] RADOS invalid argument (error calling conf_read_file) |
| has_dependent_backups | False                                                            |
| id                    | 924c6e62-789e-4e51-9748-927695fc744c                             |
| is_incremental        | False                                                            |
| name                  | inventory01_vol_backups                                          |
| object_count          | 0                                                                |
| size                  | 30                                                               |
| snapshot_id           | None                                                             |
| status                | error                                                            |
| updated_at            | 2021-08-03T23:45:50.000000                                       |
| volume_id             | 398ee974-9b83-4918-9935-f52882b3e6b7                             |
+-----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Share your cinder configuration and  logs 
 check the cinder permission and ownership for cinder config

Comment: Your ceph.conf is probably not readable for the cinder user.

Comment: Something does seem to be wrong with ceph.conf, indeed, although errno 22 is "invalid argument" and does not directly point to a permission problem. I would search for "error calling conf_read_file". My first hit is https://tracker.ceph.com/issues/19658.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused due to a bug in Cinder version 16.2.1.dev13. Updating cinder to the latest version solved the issue